# Escaped but still 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:regex: Unterminated group'

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have some trouble to figure it out on how to escape my regular expression. I already escape it with this function :

```
function escapeRegExp(string) {
    return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&')
}
```

But I still have the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:
>   regex: Unterminated group

```js
function escapeRegExp(string) {
     return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&')
}
var str = "ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent"
var search = "*Ubuntu.18*"
search = escapeRegExp(search);
var re = new RegExp('^(?=.*' + search.split(/[\s,_.:-]+/).join(')(?=.*') + ')', 'gi');
var result = re.test(str);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: In your escape function, you escape the dot, that you split out later. better apply the escape to the elemnts of the split or remove the characters that will be used to split on from your escape function.

Comment: The string you end up passing to `new RegExp()` is `^(?=.*\*Ubuntu\)(?=.*18\*)`, which has a stray backslash before the closing `)` of the first group.

Comment: you can try with an additional step: split first, then escape the parts independantly, then join.

Comment: So I don't need to escape it in my function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `*` to the character class and precede it with an optional backslash:

```
search.split(/\\?[\s,_.:*-]+/).join(')(?=.*')
```

without this the above method splits at `\.` where a period is found and leaves `\` intact which later precedes `)` in join method leading to an error.

Comment: So only the dot is causing this problem ?

Comment: Yes because it has been existing both in `escapeRegExp` function and split method. But as an aside if more non-word characters are going to be input in search phrase you may consider including them in split method.